# Mac Word - Save current page as a PDF or ExportAsFixedFormat alternative?

Tags: vba, macos, ms-word

I am trying to create a macro in Word to save the current page as a PDF with the name set by the selected text.
I have this Macro that will work in Word 2010 on PC but can't seem to find an equivalent that will work on Word 2011 for Mac (v14.1.4).

```
Sub PDF_CurrentPage_Selection()
    Dim strTemp As String
    strTemp = Selection.Text
    ActiveDocument.ExportAsFixedFormat OutputFileName:=strTemp & ".pdf", ExportFormat:=wdExportFormatPDF, Range:=wdExportCurrentPage
End Sub
```

I also have this which makes a PDF with the selected text as the filename but can't get it to do only the current page:

```
Sub SaveActiveDocAsPDF()
Dim strTemp As String
strTemp = Selection.Text
If Right(strTemp, 1) = vbCr Then strTemp = Left(strTemp, Len(strTemp) - 1)
Set mySaveAs = Dialogs(wdDialogFileSaveAs)
With mySaveAs
'Selection.Information(wdActiveEndPageNumber)
    .Name = strTemp & ".pdf"
    .Format = wdFormatPDF
    .Show
End With
End Sub
```

Thank you for any help.

Comment: What version of Word on Mac are we talking about here?

Comment: Sorry. Word 2011 for Mac (v14.1.4)

Comment: Are you sure it isn't working? You are not specifying a full pathname, so who knows where the heck it would save (the "current directory", presumably)?

Comment: on **PDF_CurrentPage_Selection()** I get an error that says "Object doesn't support this property." 
And with **SaveActiveDocAsPDF()** it brings up a save dialog box with my selection. I choose a location and it saves a pdf but it's the whole document not just the one page.

Comment: Well, I'm not surprised. Save As PDF is a feature built into Mac OS X - at the document level. So `SaveActiveDocAsPDF` simply passes through that process (also called "print to PDF"). There isn't support for turning a single page to a PDF in Word 2011 for Mac. Think about it: you can't do it in the application, so obviously you can't do it via VBA. Indeed, the PDF-making abilities of Word on Windows is one reason that some Mac users occasionally fire up Windows!

Comment: I should mention that you can at least save a single page to PDF on Mac by printing just that page to PDF.

Comment: Yeah. I was just trying to save a couple steps. I was hoping there might be a way to do it since you can do it on the PC version.
Thank you for the help.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, welcome to the inferior Word for Mac. :( I could be wrong, for the moment, that's my theory and I'm sticking to it.